# phpMyadmin Internal Server Error 500

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

Internal Server Error

500

Cpanel::Exception::IO::UnlinkError/(XID 8zg8cp) The system failed to unlink [list_and_quoted,_1] because of an error: Permission denied
 at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception/CORE.pm line 330.
    Cpanel::Exception::create("IO::UnlinkError", ARRAY(0x308fe48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception.pm line 46
    Cpanel::Exception::**ANON**(**CPANEL_HIDDEN**, ARRAY(0x308fe48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Autodie/Unlink.pm line 37
    Cpanel::Autodie::Unlink::unlink_if_exists("/var/cpanel/overquota/blocks_qrius") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Quota/OverCache.pm line 92
    Cpanel::Quota::OverCache::_unset_at_quota("blocks", "qrius") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Quota/OverCache.pm line 79
    Cpanel::Quota::OverCache::unset_user_at_blocks_quota("qrius") called at cpsrvd.pl line 2502
    cpanel::cpsrvd::verify_user_is_at_blocks_quota_or_unset("qrius") called at cpsrvd.pl line 2458
    cpanel::cpsrvd::dodoc_cpaneld() called at cpsrvd.pl line 1622
    cpanel::cpsrvd::dodoc(HASH(0x13fc000)) called at cpsrvd.pl line 1409
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_one_connection(7) called at cpsrvd.pl line 878
    cpanel::cpsrvd::script() called at cpsrvd.pl line 330

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is that the phpmyadmin interface for a user or as root via WHM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
# cd /var/cpanel/overquota/
# unlink blocks_USERNAME
```